# Filter out an array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a JSON object that is returned to me from my Web Service which I have added to an array in my AngularJS project.

I need to create a array that looks like this:

```
$scope.eventSources = [
//this is event source object #1
{
    events: [ // put the array in the `events` property
    {
        title: //POPULATE FROM MY ARRAY,
        start: //POPULATE FROM MY ARRAY,
        END: //POPULATE FROM MY ARRAY
    },
    {
        title: //POPULATE FROM MY ARRAY,
        start: //POPULATE FROM MY ARRAY,
        end: //POPULATE FROM MY ARRAY
    }
    ],
}];
```

from an array that looks like this:

```
holidays: [
{
    HOLIDAY_END: "/Date(1461538800000+0100)/"
    HOLIDAY_EVENT_ID: 1
    HOLIDAY_START: "/Date(1461106800000+0100)/"
    HOLIDAY_TITLE: "Spain     "
    USER_ID: 1
}
]
```

So as you can see the `HOLIDAY TITLE, HOLIDAY START AND HOLIDAY END` need to get added to a new array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be doable with a forEach loop that goes through your `holidays` and creates an object with the required field from each element in your `holidays`. This code should do the trick:

```
$scope.eventSources = [{events:[]}];    //set up object with array for containing data
var func = function() {    //Lets do it in a function so it's reusable
    holidays.forEach(function(hol) {    //forEach loop through the holidays array data

        $scope.eventSources[0].events.push({ //Push a new object to our eventSOurces array
            title: hol.HOLIDAY_TITLE, //Set up fields on new object
            start: hol.HOLIDAY_START,
            end: hol.HOLIDAY_END
        });    
    });
}
func(); //Call function to populate array
```

You switched between `END` and `end` in your request, so I've went with `end` as it's consistent with the other fields.

Answer (score 0):

This is a proposal with [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var data = {
        holidays: [{
            HOLIDAY_END: "/Date(1461538800000+0100)/",
            HOLIDAY_EVENT_ID: 1,
            HOLIDAY_START: "/Date(1461106800000+0100)/",
            HOLIDAY_TITLE: "Spain",
            USER_ID: 1
        }, {
            HOLIDAY_END: "/Date(1462538800000+0100)/",
            HOLIDAY_EVENT_ID: 2,
            HOLIDAY_START: "/Date(1461106800000+0100)/",
            HOLIDAY_TITLE: "France",
            USER_ID: 2
        }]
    },
    $scope = { eventSources: [{}] };

$scope.eventSources[0].events = data.holidays.map(function (a) {
    return {
        title: a.HOLIDAY_TITLE,
        start: a.HOLIDAY_START,
        end: a.HOLIDAY_END
    };
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify($scope, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Can this work if the array returned back to me contains more holidays in the array?